# Bootstrap 3 in angular2 not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to use bootstrap in angular2. I have installed the boostrap and jquery dependency with `npm install --save bootstrap` and `npm install --save jquery` respectively. This is how I reference it in my **index.html**-

```
<html>
<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('applicationStartup').catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app><button class="btn btn-primary">Hello from Angular 2</button></my-app>

</body>

</html>
```

I have applied bootstrap styling in button above but its just displaying plain HTML button. I tried with CDN's as well but couldn't see any difference.

**Is there some other config also that I need to do**. I checked on different blogs but couldn't find a relevant answer to this problem.

Thanks for any help that comes my way.

Comment: jquery should be before bootstrap. That is clearly explained in the doc, BTW: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: I changed the order by putting jquery above. But still no change.

Comment: Edit your question to explain, precisely, what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. "it's not working" is much too vague.

Comment: I want eactly what I have mentioned in the question. I don't think there's much to explain in it. I have installed dependecies and then referencing them in my `index.html`. But I do not get the styles applied from bootstrap. As you can see I have used a button and in that I have used bootstrap, but what i am seeing is plain html button with no styling. What else do i need to mention?

Comment: You need to mention that. It's far from being obvious, since everything you place inside <my-app> is replaced immediately at startup by the template of the my-app component, making it quite an awkward place to test CSS. My guess is that you're seeing it unstyled because, by the time it disappears, the bootstrap CSS styelesheet hasn't been loaded yet. You also go into great lengths explaining how you installed the bootstrap JS and jquery, although you absolutely don't need it, since you only want basic CSS to apply. That makes your "it doesn't work" very unclear.

Comment: Oh, and you forgot `rel="stylesheet"` on your link.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two cdn in your header then it will work fine:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

or you need to go project folder and run this command from cmd 
      npm install --save bootstrap
then go to angular-cli.json folder  and search for styles property in the json and include 
    "

```
styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```